# Can't access my Raring installation after adding a Quantal install

Tags: installation, 12.10, kubuntu

I use Kubuntu 13.04. The other day I installed Ubuntu (unity) 12.10 on a small partition on my laptop as I needed to test something out. My data from the kubuntu install is intact, but strangely bundled up and I am not familiar with what's going on. A picture speaks 1000 words, here is my Kubuntu install in Nautilus:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's going on and if there is a way to restore my Kubuntu install? The Quantal install is unimportant to me as it's served its purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this.

It was indeed a boot issue, and my 13.04 Kubuntu install was intact. The structure of my Kubuntu install pictured above is because I am using the BTRFS (Butter FS) filesystem, which uses subvolumes. Rescatux which would be my standard way of fixing a boot issue was not recognising this partition as an install, and advice like the excellent http://dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html#mozTocId905459 does not include provisions for installs on BTRFS. So I will give the fix below.

You will need a working linux system on this PC. I used my Ubuntu 12.10 install, but you can also use a live distribution from a DVD or USB. Start a terminal (eg. Alt+F2 and type konsole on Kubuntu, or type gnome-terminal and click on the terminal icon in Dash on regular Ubuntu).

You will need to locate what partition your non-booting installation is on. First get administrative privileges for the rest of this session by entering

```
sudo su
```

Find your linux partitions by entering

```
mount
```

which will show you which partitions are 'linux'. For me this was /dev/sda6, /dev/sda7 and /dev/sda8. You can determine which one is btrfs by using

```
blkid /dev/sda6
```

for each of the linux partitions listed. If you have multiple btrfs partitions listed I would suggest mounting all of them and listing the contents to determine which is the one you are looking for. I have only one which was /dev/sda6, replace /dev/sda6 in the steps below with the partition your non-booting install is on. Mount the partition:

```
mount /dev/sda6 /mnt/
```

you can now use grub-install to set grub to use your missing install, which should fix any issues. The trick here is to use the subvolume '@' as your root directory.

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/@ /dev/sda
```

The second argument, /dev/sda is which hard drive to put the master boot record on. If you have multiple drives, you will have to put the right device here (which is the device your BIOS is configured to try and boot from). You can reboot and your system should be fixed.

```
reboot
```

Now while your machine is rebooting, click your heels 3 times, and say 'there's no place like /home, there's no place like /home, there's no place like /home'.*

*optional

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if grub of Quantal installation is dominating your whole installation ?

You have to find out the partition of Quantal and the partition of Kubuntu.

Then it is your choice with which Linux-Installation you want to boot and login
there with concerning login-display-manager.

Here is an example, where is described how to re-install grub into correct partition :

http://dailyblogged.com/1028/booting-ubuntu-with-the-chameleon-bootloader/

In the end you would only have to know, which distribution you want to deal with as the
distribution to log in with.

Kubuntu is not lost - it is still present there. It looks only as if Kubuntu and Quantal in your machine have used the same MBR.